# End background task and wait until app becomes active again - BLE processing data

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, semaphore

my app downloads a bunch of data through BLE from a peripheral. If I lock the screen my app gets moved into the background and it starts an background task. The download finishes fine but if the processing (which takes rather long because it is a lot of data) begins the app craches because it cant connect to the database.

I want to stop the execution at that point and wait for the app to become active again, but somehow I cant achieve this. I think I need some kind of semaphore to wait for the app to become active.

Here my code so far:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    //Some other code

    //initialize flag        
    isInBackgroud = NO;

    // check if app is in the background
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(appDidEnterBackground) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];

    // check if app is in the foreground
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(appDidEnterForeground) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)appDidEnterBackground {
    NSLog(@"appDidEnterBackground");
    isInBackground = YES;
    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    NSLog(@"remaining Time: %f", [app backgroundTimeRemaining]);
    bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        NSLog(@"expirationHandler");
        [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];
}

- (void)appDidEnterForeground {
    NSLog(@"appDidEnterForeground");
    isInBackground = NO;
    if (bgTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid) {
        UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
        [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }
}

//BLE connection and reading data via notification
//when finished [self processData] is called.

- (void)processData {
    if (isInBackground) {
        //set reminder
        UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate date];
        localNotification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Data was downloaded, return to the application to proceed processing your data."];
        localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
        UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

        //end background task
        [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;

        //wait for application to become active again
        while (isInBackground) {
            NSLog(@"isInBackground");
            NSLog(@"remaining Time: %f", [app backgroundTimeRemaining]);
            sleep(1);
        }

        //process data
    }
```

So I have notices that if I call `[app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];` the app just continues running but then crashes when I want connect to my database. Thats why I added the `while(isInBackground)` loop. I know that this is not good practice because it actively wastes CPU time while doing noting. I should use a semaphore at that point, but I cant figure out how to do it.

Because I'm actively waining in that loop, `appDidEnterForegronund` is never called and the loop runs forever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be looping because your app only gets so long to process before it's stopped by iOS. Instead, when your app enters the background, set a state variable that it's in the background. Do the same for the foreground.

Only update the database if you're in the foreground, otherwise, set a state variable that tells your app that you've finished downloading, but still need to process the data. Store the data if you need to.

Then, when your app is relaunched, check the state of that variable and do the processing.

Instead of sitting in a loop waiting for some state to change, set variables, and use event-driven programming.

Comment: Thakns, somehow I didn't see this :P